# ADSL device name in Linux

Tags: traffic

How to find out device name (ADSL modem connected via Ethernet) in Linux/Ubuntu?
The name is required for using tcpdump, the connection is active and was created in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends: if you are using PPPoE, it will be `ppp${n}`, where n is allocated starting at 0, and the first available number used for a new connection.

If you are using NAT, or direct IP, it will just be the `eth${n}` interface, and communication will be through TCP/IP as normal.

The easiest way to figure out the device is probably run `ip route show` and look for the "default" line - the `dev` part of that will tell you what device is used for your default (eg: "everything else") route:

```
daniel@ki:~$ ip route show
172.16.23.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.23.5 
default via 172.16.23.1 dev eth1
```

In my example, my default route is via `eth1`.